# What is making the $_POST variable parse as empty while using PHPMailer to send the email?

Tags: php, html, forms

i have a simple form:

```html
<form method="post" action="/inc/contact.php"   id="contact-form" >         
       <div class="messages"></div>
       <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <label>Name*</label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="John Doe" name="name"
       required="required" data-error="Name is required."> 
          <div ></div>
        </div>
       </div>

       <div>
        <div >
          <label>Email*</label>
          <input type="email" placeholder="john.doe@mybusiness.com" 
        name="email" required="required" data-error="Valid email is          
    required.">
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div >
          <textarea placeholder="Your message*" name="message" 
     required="required" data-error="Please,leave us a message."></textarea>
          <div></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div ><button type="submit" name="submit">Send Message</button></div>
      </div>
      </form>
```

It send the Data to the contact.php file. I am using MailerPHP to send the emails. The mailer works fine, I have verified this without the

```
 if(empty($_POST['submit'])) {
```

statement.
If i include everything inside the If statement, nothing is sent.
Looks like the $_POST variable is indeed empty.

```
    <?php

 // This example shows making an SMTP connection with authentication.
 

 use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
 use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

 require 'phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
 require 'phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
 require 'phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

  if(!empty($_POST['submit'])) {

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;

    $mail->Host = 'host';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    //Username to use for SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'uname';
    //Password to use for SMTP authentication
    $mail->Password = 'pass';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->Port = 587;

    //Set who the message is to be sent from
    $mail->setFrom('xxx@example.com', 'First Last');
    //Set an alternative reply-to address
    $mail->addReplyTo('xxx@example.com', 'First Last');
    //Set who the message is to be sent to
    $mail->addAddress('xxx@example.com', 'John Doe');

    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = 'Subject';
    $mail->Body .= "this is a message" . $_POST['message'] ;

    try {
        $mail->send();
        echo 'Your message was sent successfully!';
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Your message could not be sent!";
      
    }

    } else {
    echo "There is a problem with the contact.html
    document!";             
    }
```

The Response of my Network tab of my Developer tools looks populated

```html
{
    "name": "sdsdsd",
    "email": "xxx@example.com",
    "message": "kjlhjkuhkkhm",
    "submit": ""
}
```

What can make the $_POST variable parse as empty?

Comment: `the form request is populated with data.`... yes but as you can see, the submit parameter has no value (because you didnt set one in the html)...it's empty. Try giving it a value, or removing the empty test - checking it was set using `isset()` ought to be sufficient.

Comment: Try `var_dump($_POST)` to see what it contains. If you don't provide a value to the submit button [the browser will choose one on its own](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/submit#omitting_the_value_attribute), but using var_dump will help you double-check what it contains, or doesn't.

Comment: `displaying in Ln:`...what is "Ln"?

Comment: @aynber the var_dump($_POST) gives me NULL

Comment: @ADyson you are right thanks. Even though this is fixed then the $_POST variable in the message body is displaying NULL

Comment: Okay, so there's actually something else going on, then, since it all looks correct. Make sure you don't have any other forms or outer buttons trying to submit. Open up your browser's developer console before you submit the page, then watch the Network tab as you submit. If you click on the request, do you see the Request parameters? Are there any redirects happening?

Comment: Okay, so there's actually something else going on, then, since it all looks correct. Make sure you don't have any other forms or outer buttons trying to submit. Open up your browser's developer console before you submit the page, then watch the Network tab as you submit. If you click on the request, do you see the Request parameters? Are there any redirects happening?

Comment: @aynber the Developer tab is displaying the request as indicated in my post you can see the details there. No outer buttons . no redirects

Comment: Are you overwriting the `$_POST` superglobal with a `json_decode()`? How is the form being submitted?

Comment: @neuticle the form is submitted using the form code that is in the post.

Comment: That form will not send a JSON encoded payload, it will be a form submit, and `$_POST` will be auto filled. The code you posted is overwriting the `$_POST` superglobal, but the `json_decode()` is giving a `null` because it's failing to parse (it's not JSON data).

Comment: @neuticle can you please suggest a solution or explain why this is happening with this form? I mean this is a super simple contact form.

Comment: Remove the line `$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);` completely. It's unnecessary and overwriting the `$_POST` superglobal

Comment: @neuticle this solved my problem, thanks! it was a series of issues but this concluded the solution. I don't know how to mark the answer as Answer

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @neuticle solved this

Remove the line:

```
$_POST =json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

completely. It's unnecessary and overwriting the $_POST superglobal"